# How can I smooth out creases in artificial turf?

Tags: flooring, carpet

I am looking for some help with smoothing out the creases in a golf green carpet I put in a simulator.

Does anyone have a technique/tool to smooth this out without pulling up the whole carpet?

There is a 1-inch foam floor below the simulator and the carpet isn't fastened to the floor or the outside wall. I have tried heavy objects and smoothing out with a 5ft piece of 1-in conduit running it along the floor.

[image]

Comment: Is it glued down?

Answer (score 1):

The carpet needs to be stretched:

Unless using a glue-down carpet, carpet is typically stretched and held in place with tack strips around the perimeter.

Tack strips are thin strips of wood with short nails sticking up and at an angle towards the outside perimeter of the room.

The stretching is done with a carpet stretcher and/or a 'knee kicker'. Both of which can be rented from the big box stores or a tool rental shop.

Tack Strips:
[image]

Carpet Stretcher:
[image]

Knee Kicker:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure if a golf green carpet can be stretched.  I could be wrong.